# Google Could Datastore - parent entity or array property

Tags: nosql, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to get my head around NoSQL and Google Cloud Datastore, and I don't know how to chose between two different options for storing data.

I have a list of orders, and every order is for an unspecified number of products. What are the pros/cons of storing the product list as an array property for the order entity vs having product child entities for each order parent?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, be well aware of the distinction between the 2 possible approaches of implementing a relationship between entities:

- one entity can contain a [Key](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#key) type property pointing to another entity (which might or might not exist!) - this is a functional relationship only, not one at the datastore level
- having the 2 datastore entities in a parent-child ([ancestry](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths)) relationship, inside the same datastore entity group.

Using the 2nd one has scalability implications, see also:

- [Ancestor relation in datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088623/ancestor-relation-in-datastore/47094411#47094411)
- [E-commerce Product Categories in Google App Engine (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015547/e-commerce-product-categories-in-google-app-engine-python/49016554#49016554)

As for storing a list as an array property vs as separate entities, see [Creating your own activity logging in GAE/P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556022/creating-your-own-activity-logging-in-gae-p/49557438#49557438) (where *repeated* properties is just how array properties are called in the `ndb` client library context).